# Jacobian of just one variable - Azimuthal average of this function

Tags: integration

Ideally I would like to get an analytical expression for the azimuthal average of a certain function:
$$ f(x,y) = \mathrm{Max}\left (0, \, 1-\frac{x^2}{R_x^2} - \frac{y^2}{R_y^2} \right )^{3/2} $$

for which I can write my azimuthal average can be written:
$$ F_az(r) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0 ^{2\pi} \mathrm{Max}\left (0, \, 1-\frac{\rho^2\cos^2\phi}{R_x^2} - \frac{\rho^2\sin^2\phi}{R_y^2} \right )^{3/2} \mathrm{d}\phi$$

Now. I want to change to an elliptical coordinate system $u = \rho \cos\phi/R_x$, $v = \rho \sin\phi/R_x$...

If the integral were over $\phi$ ***and*** $\rho$, I could do just calculate the Jacobian.

But my integral is in **one variable only**! How do I compute it?

I tried symbolic integration on Mathematica but I would not stop calculating... so I got nothing from there.

Would anyone know if there is an analytical solution? How would I start computing it?

Comment: what is the relationship between the integrand and $\phi$?

Comment: usual cartesian and plane polars, $\phi = \arctan(y/x)$

Comment: I modified the question to add more details about wat I have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

One stupid way
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(\phi)d\phi
 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^1 d\rho \int_0^{2\pi} f(\phi)d\phi
$$

Comment: Yeah but would that give an analytic solution for my $f$?

Comment: @SuperCiocia you were looking to change coordinates -- this will give you a way to do so

Comment: And I thank you for that. Mathematica still does not give me a symbolic integral. Do you know of a way to start solving my $f$? I.e. a change of variables that would make a known integral like Elliptic ones come out?

Comment: @SuperCiocia unfortunately, not